# What is the reference pin on an instrumentation amplifier used for?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

Happy new year all!

I'm wondering how to correctly use the reference pin on an INA128 Instrumentation Amplifier.  Is there a way to use this pin to eliminate negative voltages (i.e. do a voltage shift)?

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can do a voltage shift through InAmp's REF pin.  A [very similar question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/52626/7036) was posted today.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am looking for.  In the schematic on the reference section, how would you add the decoupling cap and what value?

Comment: Using this pin wrong can kill your CMMR, so be a bit careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference pin is exactly for level shifting the output. Note that it is best
to use a low impedance source for this.An op amp as a unity gain buffer or other configuration should ideally drive this pin.

For decoupling take a look at the typical application circuit in the datasheet. It recommends a 0.1uF capacitor. Perhaps an extra 10uF capacitor would also be good.