# Instrumentation Amp Voltage issue

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

Thanks for your help on the [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/52649/what-is-the-reference-pin-on-an-instrumentation-amplifier-used-for). I set up my wheatstone bridge to pins 2 and 3 of the amp. When I use a voltmeter, I see differences over the bridge as a function of resistor change. When I put my voltmeter on the output of the INA128, I see a constant voltage of ~100mv. I am supplying with 3V with the reference pin directed to ground. The voltage is 100mv even with NC at pins 2 and 3. I would have thought it should be at 0. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a schematic of your circuit? It would make it much easier for us to follow what you are saying.

Comment: Have you added the RG resistor? The part should somehow change the voltage unless something is missing or the part is bad.

Answer (score 5):

INA128 has a minimum supply voltage of 4.5V.

You are attempting to use it at 3V.  I'm not surprised it doesn't work at all.

This is on the first page of the datasheet.  I strongly suggest you read the datasheet before designing a circuit.

[image]

Comment: You are not exceeding that, but you are also not exceeding the 4.5V minimum supply.

Comment: Yup, +/- 2.25V is 4.5V single-ended.